# Regex to capture two different formats

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string in the form of a key-value pair "key1 value" and want to capture the individual words using Javascript.

I want to retrieve an array in the form: `["key1", "value"]`.

After playing around with the regex expression, I have confusion with how capturing works.

```
let str = "key1 value";
str.match(\b([a-z0-9]+)\s([a-z]+)\b/)
```

I am confused why this expression returns the following:

```
["key1 value", "key1", "value"]
```

I have one capture group containing alphanumeric numbers, but if I negate `^` the second expression then I can't capture the first.

Can someone explain what is incorrect here and how I can accomplish this?

Comment: You just want `str.match(/\b[a-z0-9]+\b/gi)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I see, I misunderstood capturing vs matching. Thank you